# Вопрос касаемо работы со строками и символами в C++

Tags: c++, строки, char

Сразу прилагаю код моей программы (его можно пропустить):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string source, result;
    string A[100];
    int j, i = 0, number_of_words, digit_word;
    bool find_digit_word = false;
    bool first_digit_word = false;

    do {
        cout << "Введите строку (не более 200 символов): \n";
        getline (cin, source);
    } while (source.length() > 200);

    //удаляем пробелы в начале строки
    while (source[0] == ' ') source.erase(0, 1);
    //удаляем запятые
    while (source.find(',,') != -1) source.erase(source.find(',,'), 1); 
    //удаляем двойные пробелы                              
    while (source.find("  ") != -1) source.erase(source.find("  "), 1);  
    //добавляем пробел в конец строки
    source = source + " ";

    //заполняем массив словами
    do {
        j = source.find(" ");
        if (j != -1) {
            A[i].assign(source, 0, j);
            source.erase(0, j+1);
            i++;
        }
    } while (j != -1);
    number_of_words = i;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++)
        if (A[i].length() != 4) A[i] = "";

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++)
        A[i].replace('A', 'O');

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++) {
        find_digit_word = true;
        for(j = 0; j < A[i].length(); j++)
            if (A[i][j] < '0' || A[i][j] > '9') find_digit_word = false;
        if (find_digit_word == true || first_digit_word == true) {
            digit_word = atoi(A[i].c_str());  
            A[i] = pow(digit_word, 3);
            first_digit_word = false;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++) {
        if (i == 0) result = result + A[i];
        else result = result + " " + A[i];
    }

    cout << "Получившаяся строка: \n" << result;   

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь работа со строками и всё подобное... 
Одной из задач является: заменить все 'A' на 'O' в каждом элементе строчного массива. Это осуществляется вот в таком цикле:

```
for(i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++)
        A[i].replace('A', 'O');
```

Так вот это всё дело не работает, компилятор жалуется на саму строчку с replace'ом и выдаёт на этот счёт следующее:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::replace(char, char)'
```

Я его так и не понял. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема, что исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите, какие перегрузки `replace` есть: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace  Вашего варианта там нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи - "Заменить все а на у" есть в stl функции replace и  replace_if (и вам не придется ручками бегать по Вашей строке)

Если Вы дергаете replace у string то делайте это так (поправите в Вашем коде)

```
    A[i].replace(A[i].find("A"), 1, "O");
```

Но это заменить только первое вхождение!! Обратите внимание на двойные " !!!!!!

Теперь минимальный пример использования вариантов решения задачи:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>


int main()
{
    std::string line{"abcdeab"};

    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    std::replace(std::begin(line), std::end(line), 'a', 'x');

    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    std::replace_if(std::begin(line), std::end(line), [](char& s){return s=='b';}, 'w');

    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    line.replace(std::begin(line) + 2, std::begin(line) + 3, 1, 'z');

    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

И так :

```
std::replace(std::begin(line), std::end(line), 'a', 'x');
```

Просто пробежится по всей Вашей строке и поменяет все 'a' на 'x'

А в

```
std::replace_if(std::begin(line), std::end(line), [](char& s){return s=='b';}, 'w');
```

Можете передать предикат с условием и натворить любую магию которую только захотите

Так же у самого класса string есть свой метод replace

```
line.replace(std::begin(line) + 2, std::begin(line) + 3, 1, 'z');
```

Тут все более управляемое - вы указывает от куда и по куда поменять и на что (по сути он отрежет все между 2-мя итераторами и воткнет туда, что Вы ему скажете. Вы можете даже просто вырезать что-то из строки указав 0 как аргумент

```
line.replace(std::begin(line) , std::begin(line) + 3, 0, ' ');
```